# Display message after submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify, liquid

I am trying to display a message if the user click in the submit button and the form is valid. I am using Shopify for that. Is there a way to do that with JavaScript or in Liquid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add onclick event and write javaScript code to validate this
ex

```
<script type='text/javaScript'>
function do()
{

}
</script>
<input type='button' onClick='do()'/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works for me. After all what I did was: if the form is not valid the button would be disabled, otherwise it would follow with the onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be a pop-up message using the following:

onclick: 'alert("Message")'

Just add that as an attribute to your button in your HTML document, with "Message" being replaced with whatever you want your message to be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was not exactly what I neede but it also works.